# How do you know if a nuget tool is thread safe (.NET)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thread-safety, rotativa

I am using a tool called Rotativa to convert MVC views to pdf. How do I know if its thread safe?

http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Rotativa

Comment: You check its documentation and/or its code.

Comment: "Thread Safe" is a pretty generic term. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I know it should be safe, simply because it spawns a new process executing wkhtmltopdf.exe for each request.

Comment: I upvoted because the answer was helpful and I saw no reason for a down vote, and the down vote didn't explicitly add a reason... Unless someone was being rude about English as a second language.